# I am using `xprintidle` to trigger a bash script after X seconds of inactivity. How do I make it loop?

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am using `xprintidle` to trigger a bash script after X seconds of inactivity.

```
#!/bin/bash
idletime=$((3*1000)) # 3 seconds in milliseconds
                     # For testing purposes, I am
                     # using 3 seconds.
idle=0

while [ $idle -lt $idletime ];do
    idle=`xprintidle`
    sleep 1
done

/my/bash/script/
```

The script above works, but it only runs once. How to I cause the script to loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enclose with a `while true` so it runs forever:

```
while true; do
    idle=0
    while [ $idle -lt $idletime ];do
        idle=`xprintidle`
        sleep 1
    done
    /my/bash/script
done
```

you might write it more succinctly:

```
while true; do (($(xprintidle) >= 3000)) && myscript; sleep 1; done
```

but, same thing

Comment: Thanks but when I ran this, `while true; do (($(xprintidle) >= 3000)) && i3lock && xtrlock & sleep 2 && xset dpms force off; sleep 1; done` it looped approximately every second. 
Therefore, I had to manually reboot my machine. By the way,  I'm running a screen locker.

Comment: yes it loops every second, if it's still idle, it will run the loop again, but if any of those programs you chained with && block, it will stop the loop until the blocking program returns (and looks like both i3lock and xtrlock do block).  not sure if you made a typo there with your single '&' instead of double '&&' which would have put the whole string of programs ending with xtrlock in the background and returned to the shell for another loop; that would be trouble as it would keep running the locker every second or in this case 3s (1 in loop + your new sleep 2).

Comment: not sure why you have two lockers, but if the single `&` is not a typo and the purpose of backgrounding is to turn the screen off 2s after the locker runs, maybe you want this: `while true; do if (($(xprintidle) >= 3000)); then (sleep 2; xset dpms force off) & xtrlock; fi; sleep 1; done`

Comment: The two lockers do different things. I use i3lock to put an image on my screen immediately prior to locking; whereas, I use xtrlock to actually lock my screen.

Comment: The single & is **not** a typo. I have no idea why it works with a single & but it does. It does not work with two &s.

Comment: `while true; do if (($(xprintidle) >= 3000)); then (sleep 2; xset dpms force off) & xtrlock; fi; sleep 1; done` does not work for me at all. In other words, nothing happens when I run it.

Comment: Currently I can lock my screen manually by running this script, `i3lock -u -i '/home/pictures/image.png' && sleep 4 && xtrlock & sleep 2 && xset dpms force off` That works fine. But sometimes I forget to lock my screen prior to walking away from my computer. In those cases my screen does not lock. I use Lubuntu 20.04 which comes with XScreenSaver. I despise XScreenSaver, therefore I uninstalled it. I'm trying to "roll my own" solution. In theory it seems like it should be easy to trigger my current script to run with `xprintidle` after X minutes of inactivity. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I ran the exact command you say "does not work for [you] at all," pasted directly from your text onto a bash prompt, and it works fine on my computer.  After 3s idle, it runs xtrlock, I see the padlock, then 2s later the screen turns off.  If you can't reproduce that, and it works fine on my system with identical commands, I don't know how to help.

Comment: Oh. Good. Thanks for letting me know. I have another machine that I can try running your script on. I'll give that a try within the next 24 hours or so and then report back to you.

Comment: I just successfully ran `while true; do if (($(xprintidle) >= 3000)); then (sleep 2; xset dpms force off) & xtrlock; fi; sleep 1; done` on my other machine! Thanks for taking the time to work with me on this. I appreciate your help!